# Form launchs a procedure without filling cells beforehand

Tags: vba, excel, stored-procedures

I've written a procedure that should determine some values, enter them in specific cells and launch a procedure that depends on these same cells.

It worked once, but then the proc started to act like the cells were empty.

The form contains three textboxes (ratebox, amountbox, cfbox), as well as one combobox:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If ratebox.value = "" Or amountbox.value = "" Or numbercfbox.value = "" Or cfbox.value = "" _
Or Not IsNumeric(ratebox.value) Or Not IsNumeric(amountbox.value) Or Not IsNumeric(cfbox.value) Or Not IsNumeric(numbercfbox.value) Then
MsgBox "valeur"
Exit Sub
End If

Cells(3, 1) = ratebox.value / 100
Cells(3, 2) = amountbox.value

For i = 1 To numbercfbox.value
Cells(3, i + 2) = cfbox.value
Next

callproc_e1

Unload form_e1

End Sub
```

The procedure starts with:

```
Sub e1s1()
rate = Cells(3, 1)
amount = Cells(3, 2)
numbercf = Cells(3, 3).End(xlToRight).column - 2
'MsgBox (rate & Chr(10) & amount & Chr(10) & numbercf)
ReDim cf(numbercf) As Double
```

I've tried registering the box values in variables and entering the variables in the cell before launching the procedure, doesn't work.
I've put a msgbox with all the values just before launching the procedure:

```
Cells(3, i + 2) = cfbox.value
Next

MsgBox (ratebox.value & Chr(10) & amountbox.value & Chr(10) & numbercfbox.value & Chr(10) & cfbox.value)

callproc_e1
```

When the msgbox appears, I can see that the values are written down in the cells, but the procedure still acts like these cells are empty: numbercf is 16382.

Comment: might be worth trying with a `.Value` after the `Cells(x, y)`, to give `cells(x, y).Value`

Comment: @tospig I've tried, the numbercf is still 16382 for the proc, meaning the cells are seen as being empty. I don't know if it's relevant, but when I add the .value, it stays lowercase, like Cells(x, y).value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will fill cells in the active worksheet of the active workbook.  If it fails sometimes, you should specify the sheet with lines like:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 1) = ratebox.value / 100
```

Comment: I've done it both in the form and the module, still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally located the problem: in my call sub, the first action was to delete all cells.

Thanks to all those who tried to help.